# Error while connecting to Alfresco repository using opencmis and SSO

Tags: java, web-services, rest, alfresco, opencmis

I have an Alfresco server running on xx.xx.xx.101, I am connecting my Java workspace to it, my workspace and alfresco have been wired using SSO . So whenever I click on any link in jsp page, without authenticating I will be redirecting to Alfresco share page .

This is my code for logging into Alfresco repository

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(SessionParameter.USER, userName);
        params.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
        params.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL,
 "http://10.139.1.217:81/alfresco/service/cmis");
        params.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE,
 BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
        params.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS,
 DMS_CONST.KBRREPOSITORYFACTORYIMPL);
        List<Repository> repos = sessionFactory.getRepositories(params);
        return repos.get(0).createSession();
```

For username I pass ROLE_TICKET and for password I pass ticket_value retrieved from Alfresco Share.

The problem is whenever I execute this code I get a

> com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException:  in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a system identifier.
>    at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,62]
>
> http://10.139.1.217:8

One URL is my SSO URL , my actual URL of the machine on which alfresco is running is different.

Comment: In the question you say your server is on `.101` but in the code you give `.217` - could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use the below url -

```
parameters.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom");
```